# Windows Server 2019 GPO won't copy fonts to C:\Windows\Fonts

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2019

Link to picture: https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/pwQHQ7qj8ere.png

I'm trying to deploy Fonts via GPO but they refuse to be installed inside the Window folder. I tried just about every method. I also did a mock location at C:\Test and the Fonts get deployed successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: `C:\Windows\Fonts` is a protected folder and installations are typically managed by Windows Installer. For this to work, SYSTEM would need to be granted traditional Full Control.

Comment: Any hints how to do this through GPO, if this is even a suggested practice?

Comment: The suggested practice would be to create an MSI with the fonts to copy and deploy using the usual and customary configuration management solution.  https://www.hass.de/content/how-create-msi-deploying-fonts-enterprise

Comment: Is this an update type action? Does it check if the package is already installed or will it trigger after every reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very probably, you made a mistake and tried to use the file deployment of the user configuration section and not the computer config section. Because it works there. Please note, that the file alone does not suffice, but you need to deploy a regkey into HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts as well, example:[image]